# How to write the kafka consumer logs into a file in linux

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to write the logs that prints in my console. I am seeing the messages in the topic in Kafka consumer, however, nothing is being written to the log file (my_log_file.txt)
But when I do "echo 'test' | >> text.txt", a file is being generated.

Please help.

My command:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server1.server.com:9092, server2.server.com:9092, server3.server.com:9092 --topic MY-SAMPLE-TOPIC >> my_log_file.txt
```

Comment: I don't have kafka with me so can't test, could you please try following once `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server1.server.com:9092, server2.server.com:9092, server3.server.com:9092 --topic MY-SAMPLE-TOPIC >> my_log_file.txt 2>&1` ? if that works for you?

Comment: if you want this to happen every time you run the shell script then you can also update the script to have - exec &>> your_file.log at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Kafka Connect for this... Console consumer will not track offsets without giving a consumer group

```
bin/connect-standalone config/connect-standalone.properties config/file-sink.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

By default kafka-console-consumer.sh reads data from latest offset. So you must continue to  send data during kafka-console-consumer is working. If you want to read from beginning you can use this command (it will process up to 100 messages because of `--max-messages` parameter):

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server1.server.com:9092, server2.server.com:9092, server3.server.com:9092 --from-beginning --max-messages 100 --topic MY-SAMPLE-TOPIC >> my_log_file.txt
```

Or you can set offset by `--offset x --partition y` parameter to consume from specific offset.